# Angular: What is the significance of link option in directive

Tags: angularjs

i am learning angular and some time stumble to understand code and their significance. see the sample below code and tell me what is link option in directives ?

what kind of purpose link option solve or does ? when code inside link option fire ? please give me some insight about link option. thanks

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.directive('ngFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                if (scope.$last === true) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        scope.$eval(attr.ngFinishRender);
                    }, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.lists = [
            { name: 'A', isShow: true },
            { name: 'B', isShow: true },
            { name: 'C', isShow: false },
            { name: 'D', isShow: false },
            { name: 'E', isShow: true },
            { name: 'F', isShow: true },
        ];

        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.lists[2].isShow = true;
        }, 3000);

        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.lists[3].isShow = true;
        }, 6000);      

        $scope.finish = function () {
            console.log('finish');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please read the documentation on Angular directives https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this page https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
Here you can read about link option in directives.

> Directives that want to modify the DOM typically use the **link** option to register DOM listeners as well as update the DOM. It is executed after the template has been cloned and is where directive logic will be put.

For an instance;

Here is our controller;

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('hotArea', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, atts) {
            element.bind("mouseover", function(){
                element.addClass("areaOn");
                console.log("mouseove");
            });
            element.bind("mouseout", function(){
                element.removeClass("areaOn");
                console.log("mouseove");
            });
        }
    };
}
);

myApp.controller('myController',function($scope){});
```

And our html page;

```
<style>
     .areaOn { border: 3px solid red; }
     .areaOff { border: none;}
</style>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div hot-area>This is an area</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When you run this code snippet you will notice that the directive we defined would be able to modify the DOM. In this example, we marked an area as "hotArea" and for this area "mouseover" and "mouseout" functions have a different behaviour than the default one.

Comment: better come with example which show the importance of working with link option. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Angular traverse all the elements in the dom and search for directive declaration, then it compile them and attach the functionality related to those directives.

The link function in a directive fire after the compile phase, and serve as superpower controller, with the ability to require and use other directives and their controllers around the element, and of course - manipulate the element, listen to events, etc. so you can manipulate the dom according to your scope value, for example.

Comment: better come with example which show the importance of working with link option. thanks